# doctrine DQL orderBy with Max value

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

i have an entity with parent_id field and a sequence field (integer).

i would like to order by Parent_id field, and select lines with Max sequence only.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach with query builder and subselect.

Use this method in your entityRepository class:

```
public function getQueryBuilderForMaxSequenceValue()
    {
        $sub = $this->createQueryBuilder('a2');
        $sub->select("max(a2.sequence)");

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
        $qb->where('u.sequence= ( '.$sub->getDQL().' )');
        $qb->orderBy('u.parent_id','DESC');


        return $qb;
    }
```

Hope this help